# How To Validate Hex Colors using loop regex and an array?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, validation, foreach

I have two colorpicker fields and I am using `preg_match` to validate them. This is a **working** code, ***it validates as expected.*** 
It looks like this (I will give code for first field because second field is basically the same):

```
function display_bg_setting($args){
//Get our options from register settings (my_theme_color_options);
$GetColorpickerValue = (array) get_option('my_theme_color_options');

if(isset($GetColorpickerValue['display_bg'])) {
$get_options = $GetColorpickerValue['display_bg'];
}   else {
     $GetColorpickerValue['display_bg']='';
     $get_options = $GetColorpickerValue['display_bg'];
    }
echo'<input type="text" id="display_bg" value="'.$get_options.'" name="my_theme_color_options[display_bg]" />';
```

**Now The Question:** 
Obviously i will have a lot more colorpicker fields in my theme (15-20 fields) so instead validating every single field like in the code above I tried to use a callback function and validate my colors simultaneously. This is where I am failing and  my code does not validate colors.

The callback looks like this:

```
  function validate_color_options_and_other_fields($options){
  //My two colopickers fields stored as an array
  $option = array($options['wrapper_background_color'],$options['display_bg']);

  foreach($option as $options){
    if(preg_grep('/#([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3}(([a-f]|[A-F]|[0-9]){3})?\b/', $options)) //hex color is valid

    {
         return $options;//Returns colorpicker fields
    } 


     else {//Returns blank
     $options['wrapper_background_color']='';
     $options['display_bg']='';
     } 

    }//End foreach


   return $options;//Returns all other options(checkboxses,select fields...)


}//Function end
```

This is what I am trying to do: 
I put some ***non-color value*** on **first field** and ***real color*** on **second field** so the output would be **nothing** on first field and **real color** on second field and vice versa.(This is the part where my callback fails.). 
Or I put some ***non-color values*** on **both fields** and it returns **nothing** on both fields (This is the part where my callback works.)

Can you guys help me out with this?

Comment: In your validate function you are mixing around the $options/$option variables. Your $option variable is not used as you are overwriting it in the foreach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `preg_grep` which uses an array as input, but you are giving at a string by your foreach.
I think the easiest would be using something like the following code:

```
$options = array('#fffAA9', '#a65c23');

foreach ($options as $value)
{
    preg_match('/(#[a-f0-9]{3}([a-f0-9]{3})?)/i', $value, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1]))
    {
        // validated ok
        var_dump($matches[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        // no match
    }
}
```

edit:
Alternativly you can do it with preg_grep even simpler:

```
public function actionValidate($options)
{
//  $options = array('#fffAA9', '#a65c23');

    return preg_grep('/^(#[a-f0-9]{3}([a-f0-9]{3})?)$/i', $options);
}
```